# Ubuntu server to desktop without screwing grub

Tags: ubuntu, grub

this is my system:

- Windows 7 on an SSD
- Ubuntu Server on a SATA hard drive

I need to remove Ubuntu Server and install Ubuntu Desktop, without causing a fuss.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the difference between ubuntu server and desktop is primarily the kernel. Install the ubuntu desktop metapackage (or kubuntu... or) if you want a GUI. If you really want, install the 'regular' kernel and uninstall the server kernel. Reboot.

Comment: i would really love a clean install of the desktop

Comment: in that case, what kind of fuss are you worried about? what specifically are you trying to avoid?

Comment: maybe i'm making a big fuss myself. so, should i just install ubuntu desktop, select the same HDD, overwrite the server, and everything works fine?

Comment: yup, assuming the bootloader's installed to the right place, depending on your setup. If you're using windows bootloader and ubuntu's bootloader on seperate partitions, i'd suggest disconnecting the windows HDD to be sure. else, it ought to work fine.

Comment: so, i went with installing kubuntu. i think i'm alright